# Generating AA, AB, ..., ZZ in excel using numbers 0-25

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created column as mentioned below:

```
0   A   00
1   B   01
2   C   02
3   D   03
4   E   04
5   F   05
6   G   06
7   H   07
8   I   08
9   J   09
10  K   010
```

I have two columns , first column has 0-10 and second column has A-K and I have created a new column with combinations of AA , AB till ZZ in numbers as in 00 , 01 till 010. I need to substitute the number with the alphabets using vlookup and if condition . Kindly help me with it

Can I do it with help of `=Vlookup()` and/or `=If()` condition alone?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not really sure what you're after, I can't read your initial starting data very clearly ?

To replace a value, you can:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"0","A")
```

not sure if that does what you want, though?

Comment: I've made an edit of the question. Please check if the data is more clear now.

Comment: I have a 1st row - 0    A   00

Comment: I have two columns , first column has 0-25 and second column has A-Z and I have created a new column with combinations of AA , AB till ZZ in numbers as in 00 , 01   till 2626. I need to substitute the number with the alphabets using vlookup and if condition . Kindly help me with it

Comment: Ok, so so what does "105" translate to ?  KF ? or BF? and why? How do I know where to break the numbers ?

Comment: First we should assign 0 = A , 1=B ....10=K and then we can proceed . i'm not sure how to assign it

Comment: @user2865419 . sorry, that doesn't make sense. so given:  "100"  what does that translate to?  KA ? or BAA ? you haven't explained how to seperate this string of 1's and 0's into seperate values .. without that .. this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start a new answer, it's different enough from the first post.

So, taking your initial data:
I add 2 more columns: It's simply the mapping of Column C, split out into column D and E. At time of writing this, I have no idea how you translate that programatically, so until we have the rules, I'll just do this . and we can plug that other part in later.

```
  0   A   00    0   0
  1   B   01    0   1
  2   C   02    0   2
  3   D   03    0   3
  4   E   04    0   4
  5   F   05    0   5
  6   G   06    0   6
  7   H   07    0   7
  8   I   08    0   8
  9   J   09    0   9
  10  K   010   0   10
```

And then use this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$B$11,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(E1,$A$1:$B$11,2,FALSE))
```

and you'll end up with this:

```
  AA
  AB
  AC
  AD
  AE
  AF
  AG
  AH
  AI
  AJ
  AK
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is to generate **AA** thru **ZZ,** first enter the following *UDF* in a standard module:

```
Public Function BumpString(s As String) As String
    Dim aryIN(1 To 1000) As Integer
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, carry As Boolean
    L = Len(s)
    j = 1
    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        aryIN(j) = Asc(Mid(s, i, 1))
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    For i = 1 To L
        carry = False
        aryIN(i) = aryIN(i) + 1
        If aryIN(i) = 91 Then
            aryIN(i) = 65
            carry = True
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If carry Then
        L = L + 1
        aryIN(L) = 65
    End If

    For i = 1 To L
        BumpString = Chr(aryIN(i)) & BumpString
    Next i
End Function
```

Then pick a cell, say **D1** and enter **AA**
Below it enter:

```
=bumpstring(D1)
```

Then copy **D2** down thru **D676**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `VLOOKUP` for this.

You can use the [`CODE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/code.php) function with the first and last character:

```
=(CODE(LEFT(A1))-65) & (CODE(RIGHT(A1))-65)
```

Note that many combinations will map to the same number, such as "BU" and "MA":

[image]